# Llenar una etiqueta option con un for

Tags: html, angular

Quiero hacer un `select` que tenga una etiqueta `option` la cual se llene con valores del 1 al 8

```
<select class="num_per" [(ngModel)]="personas" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="personas">
   <option class="placeholder" [value]="valor" class="tagHidden" disabled>Personas</option>
   <option value="2" ></option>
   <option value="Solicitud de cotización">8 + Solicita cotización aquí 
   </option>
</select>
```

En la primera etiqueta `option` es la que deseo que se llene con valores del 1 al 8, estos valores del 1 al 8 pueden venir desde un array o de cualquier forma ya que utilizo angular para crear las paginas web.

Gracias por leer.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con algo como esto.

```
<select class="num_per" [(ngModel)]="personas" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="personas">

    <option value="{{i}}" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">{{i}}</option>

</select>
```